# Programmatically clear cache in Internet Explorer 8 on Windows 7

Tags: http, caching, batch-file

I'm writing a script to test our Internet performance. Basically it opens IE, browses to a website (like yahoo.com), exits IE, clears cache, and repeats

The problem I'm having is that the IE cache is not being fully cleared. I know this because we looked at some packets and found many HTTP requests for webpage objects that returned 304, meaning that the cache wasn't cleared.

I've tried two options, manually clearing the temp folder, and using the command

```
RunDll32.exe InetCpl.cpl,ClearMyTracksByProcess 255
```

but neither seems to fully clear the cache. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: try to delete everything in `..\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\`

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer is much more tricker. It stores history, cookies and cache all over the place, including registry.

I think below works for you as it deletes all that data from all the places:

```
@echo off

set DataDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Intern~1

del /q /s /f "%DataDir%"
rd /s /q "%DataDir%"

set History=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History

del /q /s /f "%History%"
rd /s /q "%History%"

set IETemp=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Tempor~1

del /q /s /f "%IETemp%"
rd /s /q "%IETemp%"

set Cookies=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies

del /q /s /f "%Cookies%"
rd /s /q "%Cookies%"
```

Optionally,If you also want to remove the data from registry, you can add following step above:

```
C:\bin\regdelete.exe HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TypedURLs"
```

Notice that the last command is regdelete.exe. It's a small win32 utility written in c++ that erases the IE history, because it stores it in registry.

Here is the regdelete.c program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
// compile as: mingw32-g++ regdelete.c -o regdelete.exe -mwindows

#define eq(s1,s2) (strcmp((s1),(s2))==0)

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR cmdLine, int nCmdShow) 
{ 
    if (!cmdLine || !strlen(cmdLine)) {
        printf("Usage: regdel.exe <HKEY> <path to regkey> - be careful not to delete whole registry\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int argc;
    LPWSTR *argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &argc);

    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: regdel.exe <HKEY> <path to regkey> - be careful not to delete whole registry\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char **argv8 = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * argc);
    for (int i = 0; i<argc; i++) {
        int len = wcslen(argv[i]);
        argv8[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(len+1));
        wcstombs(argv8[i], argv[i], len+1);
    }

    HKEY hkey;
    if (eq(argv8[1], "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT")) {
        hkey == HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
    }
    else if (eq(argv8[1], "HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG")) {
        hkey = HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG;
    }
    else if (eq(argv8[1], "HKEY_CURRENT_USER")) {
        hkey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
    }
    else if (eq(argv8[1], "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")) {
        hkey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    }
    else if (eq(argv8[1], "HKEY_USERS")) {
        hkey = HKEY_USERS;
    }
    else {
        printf("Unknown hkey\n");
        return 1;
    }

    HKEY key;
    int status = RegOpenKeyEx(hkey, argv8[2], 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &key);
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("failed opening %s\n", argv8[2]);
        return 1;
    }

std::vector<std::string> vals;

for (unsigned int i = 0; ; i++) {
    DWORD size = 1024;
    char val[size+1];
    DWORD type;
    status = RegEnumValue(key, i, val, &size, NULL, &type, NULL, NULL);
    if (status == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) break;
    if (status == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        vals.push_back(std::string(val));
        continue;
    }
    printf("failed enumerating %s\n", argv8[2]);
    return 1;
}

typedef std::vector<std::string>::iterator vsi;
for (vsi i = vals.begin(); i != vals.end(); i++) {
    status = RegDeleteValue(key, i->c_str());
    if (status != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        printf("failed deleting %s\n", i->c_str());
        return 1;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Just compile above program and you can use this regdelete.exe in your batch.